# Getting Keyerror 0 during SQL Import process in Python Script

Tags: python, json, sql-server, import, active-directory

I am getting the below error when running a python SQL import from a JSON file.  Code is below.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21192\1603560781.py in <module>
     56 for row in ad_users_list:
     57     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.testpyimport (Enabled,givenName,sn,displayName,description,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,telephoneNumber,mail,streetAddress,l,st,postalCode,co,sAMAccountName,mobile,facsimileTelephoneNumber,ipPhone,title,department,manager,company,distinguishedname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
---> 58             row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21])
     59 
     60 

KeyError: 0
```

Code:

```
import pyodbc
import pyad.adquery
import subprocess
import json

# Define the PowerShell command to retrieve AD user information
powershell_command = r'''
$adUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=IT,OU=Users,OU=TX,OU=TESTUSA,DC=Test,DC=com'
$adUsers | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Enabled = $_.Enabled
        givenName = $_.givenName
        sn = $_.sn
        displayName = $_.displayName
        description = $_.description
        physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
        telephoneNumber = $_.telephoneNumber        
        mail = $_.mail
        streetAddress = $_.streetAddress
        l = $_.l
        st = $_.st
        postalCode = $_.postalCode
        co = $_.co
        sAMAccountName = $_.sAMAccountName
        mobile = $_.mobile
        facsimileTelephoneNumber = $_.facsimileTelephoneNumber
        ipPhone = $_.ipPhone
        title = $_.title
        department = $_.department
        manager = $_.manager
        company = $_.company
        distinguishedname = $_.distinguishedname        
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json
'''

# Run the PowerShell command and capture the output
completed_process = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", powershell_command], capture_output=True, text=True)

if completed_process.returncode == 0:
    # Parse the JSON output and store it in a Python list
    ad_users_list = json.loads(completed_process.stdout)
    print(ad_users_list)
else:
    print("Error:", completed_process.stderr)


# Connect to database using trusted connection
connection_string = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=SQLSERVER\TESTDB;Database=scratch;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

# Create a cursor object
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Importing AD_User_List to SQL DB
for row in ad_users_list:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.testpyimport (Enabled,givenName,sn,displayName,description,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,telephoneNumber,mail,streetAddress,l,st,postalCode,co,sAMAccountName,mobile,facsimileTelephoneNumber,ipPhone,title,department,manager,company,distinguishedname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21])
       

# Commit changes to the database
conn.commit()

# Close the database connection
conn.close()`
```

I am expecting one for one import of the ADQuery into SQL Datebase Table.  There are limitations with TSQL that doesn't allow for a direct import from Active Directory.

Comment: Have you tried dumping `row` to the console? Does it always contain 22 items? What happens to any ADUser properties that are `null` when you roundtrip them through JSON?

Comment: I think I have it working from AD to SQL, now the command in not pulling all the AD Attributes that the command in Powershell ISE is returning.  It has a lot of NULL values.  So I just need to fix that issue.  The JSON output is what I expect now.